# Excel VBA No cells were found

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following sample codes to filtered out data and paste to another sheet.

I have already use is not empty to avoid the situation, but I still have the "No cell" error and I am also sure that the file marked as "No cell" should actually has data which meet the criteria.

```
Set vFind = Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Find(what:="0", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not vFind Is Nothing Then
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=0"
    copyRange1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=thisws.Cells(RowNo, 3)
    copyRange2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=thisws.Cells(RowNo, 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have, takes the `Range("B2:B" & lastRow)` of the **currently active sheet**. 
 
To make sure you're taking the right data, try adding the worksheet name before the `Range` calling, like this:

```
Worksheets("SheetName").Activate
Set vFind = Worksheets("SheetName").Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Find(what:="0", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not vFind Is Nothing Then
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=0"
    copyRange1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=thisws.Cells(RowNo, 3)
    copyRange2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=thisws.Cells(RowNo, 4)
```

Comment: You are right. I found the issue also. Thanks for answering.